# Node.js app is not able to render hbs in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am currently trying to deploy a website using Cloud Functions for Firebase and hosting features of firebase. However, I am currently experiencing a strange bug after successfully deploying my app in firebase.

The app works perfectly when I test it in localhost by using `firebase serve --only functions,hosting`

But after deploying when I try to access my hosting url. I get this error in my cloud functions logs:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'hbs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at new View (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:79:30)
    at EventEmitter.render (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
    at /user_code/routes/homepage.js:7:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

This is how I have set up my app.js in `functions folder`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const homepage = require('./routes/homepage');

const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use('/',homepage);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This is my `homepage.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const homepageRouter = express.Router();


/* GET Homepage. */
homepageRouter.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('I was called');
    res.render('./homepage/homepage.hbs');
});


module.exports = homepageRouter;
```

This is my folder structure:

[image: folder-structure-image]

Now since in the error-logs, it said this: `at /user_code/routes/homepage.js:7:9`

I thought this line of code is causing the problem: `res.render('./homepage/homepage.hbs');` in `homepage.js` But I am not able to figure out the problem since it works when trying to test in the localhost.

I think I am missing something. Any advice suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to solve using this one

[express-hbs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-hbs)

[hbs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hbs)

[express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars)